# NLTK corpus reader paragraph

Tags: text-files, nltk

I tried to copy paste content from word document (.docx) to a .txt file and made it read by a nltk corpus reader to find number of paragraph. It returns almost 30 paragraph as one paragraph. I manually entered a line break in .txt file and it returned 30 paragraphs.

```
import nltk
corpusReader = nltk.corpus.reader.plaintext.PlaintextCorpusReader(".", "d.txt")
print "Paragraphs =", len(corpusReader.paras())
```

1. Is it possible for PlaintextCorpus reader to read .docx?
2. While copy pasting from .docx to .txt, How to preserve line break?
3. Is there a way using python,where I open .txt file and find ?!or . or ... and followed by some blank spaces(4 in number) and press "enter" to create line break automatically?
           break.

Edit 1.

Walked the **para_block_reader=read_line_block** path, but it always gives one paragraph count extra.

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus.reader.util import *
corpusReader = nltk.corpus.reader.plaintext.PlaintextCorpusReader(".", "d.txt",para_block_reader=read_line_block)
print "Paragraphs =", len(corpusReader.paras())
```

Comment: You're getting an extra paragraph because the last line in your file is terminated by a newline. It's normal, and you could just decide to live with it (just write code that doesn't choke on empty paragraphs).

Comment: Don't edit your question to include the answer in the question text. This is not how this site is supposed to work. Accepting an answer is enough (and better, since the answer can be upvoted and edited independently of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plaintext corpus reader can only read plain-text files. There are Python libraries that can read docx, but that will not address *your* problem, which is that Word delimits paragraphs by a single line break, but plaintext documents traditionally understand a paragraph boundary to be a blank line-- i.e., two successive newlines. In other words, your export method *does* preserve the newlines; it's just that there's not enough of them.

So there is an easy way to fix up your texts so that paragraphs are recognized without extra to-do: Once you've written out your plaintext file (which you can do from Word's `Save As...` menu or by cutting and pasting), post-process it like this (add `encoding=` arguments as necessary):

```
with open("my_plaintext.txt") as oldfile:
    content = oldfile.read()

content = re.sub("\n", "\n\n", content)

with open("my_plaintext_fixed.txt", "w") as newfile:
    newfile.write(content)
```

You can now read `myplaintext_fixed.txt" with the`PlaintextCorpusReader`, and everything will work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The source code for PlainTextCorpus reader is the first class defined on [this page](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/corpus/reader/plaintext.html), it is fairly simple.

It has sub-components, if you don't secify them in the constructor it uses the NLTK defaults

- `para_block_reader` (default: `read_blankline_block`), which says how the document is broken up into paragraphs.
- `sentence_tokenizer` (default: English Punkt), which says how to break a paragraph into sentences
- `word_tokenizer` (default `WordPunctTokenizer()`), which says how to break a sentence into tokens (words, and symbols).

Note that the defaults may change in different versions, on NLTK. I feel like the default `word_tokenizer` used to be the Penn tokenizer.

#### Re: 1.

No PlaintextCorpus reader can not read Docx. It only reads plain text.
I'm sure you can find a python library to convert it

#### Re 2

Copy and Paste is offtopic for this site, try SuperUser.
I suggest though you instead use option 1 and get a library to do the conversion.

#### Re 3

Yes, you can do a search and replace using Regex.

```
 import re
 def breakup(mystring):
      return re.replace(mystring, r"(\.|\!|\.\.\.)    ", "\n")
```

But perhaps instead you might want to swap out your `para_block_reader` or `sent_tokenizer`